# selenium: TypeError: 'FirefoxWebElement' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I'm getting a `TypeError: 'FirefoxWebElement' object is not subscriptable` when trying to click on a link in Google:

[image]

This is the code that's getting that error:

```
    button_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(@class,'cTsG4')]")
    button_element[0].click()
```

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: I think that your problem is with `find_element_by_xpath`. Try with `find_elements_by_xpath` (elements with `s` and not element). If this resolves the problem please tell me to post it as an answer.

Comment: You can for sure use `find_element_by_xpath` but then you'll get one element and not a list.

Comment: @IlSaggioVecchino You're right! Please post it as an answer. If you could explain why that would be great.

Comment: Done. I edited my answer and added the explanation for the "why" of the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is due to the fact that `find_element_by_xpath` is returning one element and not a list, thus `TypeError: 'FirefoxWebElement' object is not subscriptable`. But what in the world does subscriptable mean ? well, it basically means that the object implements the `__getitem__()` method. In other words, it describes objects that are "containers", meaning they contain other objects. This includes lists, tuples, and dictionaries.
In your case button_element is unsubscriptable.

So you just need to click the button this way `button_element.click()` and not `button_element[0].click()`.

If you have many buttons satisfying the XPath that you want to click all of them, you can use `find_elements_by_xpath` (elements and not element), this will return a list that you can manipulate by iterating over its elements.

Answer (score 0):

There is a slight Typo in the script, it should be:

```
button_element = find_elements_by_xpath("//span[contains(@class,'cTsG4')]")
```

as It returns List Of Xpaths so ,  button_element[0].click() can be used

insted of

```
find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(@class,'cTsG4')]")
```

as It itself return The First Xpath found so, button_element[0].click() will

generate the TypeError as List is subscriptable but Single Element (object) isn't